# Recompiling old ASP.NET page .dll's from new VB Codebehind?

Tags: asp.net

I'm the newly appointed tech-guy at a small company.  I've inherited their near-complete ASP.NET web page that's been left "near-complete" for some time, but I'm not really familiar with ASP.NET.  It was dropped by the original developers a few years ago, and a year or so back someone tried to finish it using only inline code.

Now that I've unearthed the old VB source files, I've made a one-line change to the `Page.aspx.v`b and need get it associated to it's `Page.aspx` file.  Trouble is, the `@Page` directive directly inherits its own `App_Web_Page.xxxxxx.dll`.  Every page does this.  This is not reflected in the source I have to work with, but is the way it now operates.  The last person to touch it has long since forgotten the details of his work, and I'm not familiar enough with ASP.NET to know what to ask.

So my @Page directive goes like so:

```
<%@ page language="vb" autoeventwireup="false"  inherits="Page,
       App_Web_page.aspx.cdcab7d2" masterpagefile="~/Master.Master"
       enablesessionstate="True"  enableEventValidation="false" %>
```

When I try to precompile the site, my @Page directives look totally different:

```
<%@ page language="vb" autoeventwireup="false" Codebehind="Page.aspx.vb"
       inherits="Project.Page" masterpagefile="~/Master.Master"
       enablesessionstate="True"  enableEventValidation="false" %>
```

And, being precompiled, It doesn't yield a page-unique .dll file I can just swap into the live bin directory and change the `@Page` directive for.  I've tried a number of permutations on the @Page directive to try to get it to compile the new VB code on access, but I always wind up with errors, the best of which tell me ASP elements in the .aspx aren't defined in the .aspx.vb.

Can someone point me in the right direction with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to select the option like below highlighted...

[image]

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Express 2010, where this is not listed in any of the several places I've found to describe compilation settings.

Comment: As you mentioned about the individual page dll, you can find this dialog box, on right clicking the website in your project explorer. Now select the Publish Website option. This will show you the dialog box as shown above. Now selecting the highlighted option will enable you to prepare the dll of individual file/Folder. The point to note down here is of you have minor change in your website, you just need to place the published dll of the corresponding file only. Hope this will help you.

Comment: VS Express 2010 also does not allow the publishing of ASP.NET Web Sites, so I couldn't find that dialog if I wanted to.  However, command line compiling with the `-fixednames` option only generates .dll's for two of my pages fifteen or so pages.

Comment: Did you check the publish option by right clicking the project in the solution explorer ? I used to do it in my live project to deploy the page(s) live..

Comment: Indeed, I have checked.  Upon review, Microsoft is pretty explicit about the omission of this feature in the Express version of VS2010.  As far as I can tell, the check box you refer to is the same as the `-fixednames` switch for `aspnet_compiler`, so I believe my original question is answered.  Now I've got to figure out why it's only generating a couple `App_Web_Page.aspx.xxxxxx` dll's instead of all the ones I need.